# Access and set a static variable with the name of the variable

Tags: java

What I want to do is access a variable stored in one class with a string.
For example I have

```
public class Values {
    public static boolean enabled;
}
```

And then in a different part of the project I have the object and a string with the fields name. How do I get and set the value of the field?

Comment: I'm not sure what's worse: the blatant global state or the inappropriate use of reflection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have the name as a string, you should use reflection:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;


public class Values {

    public static boolean enabled = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {           
        Values v = new Values();

        Field field = v.getClass().getField("enabled");

        field.set( v, true );

        System.out.println( field.get(v) );         
    }

}
```

Comment: Suggestion. OP asked also how to get value of field, so maybe use in code something like `System.out.println(field.get(v));` instead of `System.out.println( Values.enabled );`. Anyway nice example. +1

Comment: Nice catch, didn't notice that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Values.enabled = true;
```

or

```
Values.enabled = false;
```

Alternatively, you can create a static getter and setter for the `Values` class and call those static methods instead.

Comment: The only problem with this is that all I have is a string with the name of the field and the Values object. Could I use reflection to get and set the boolean?

Comment: With a string; I think the OP is asking about reflection.

Answer (score 1):

@Maricio Linhares's answer is very good; however, note that reflection is pretty slow. If you are doing this a lot you might have performance problems. An alternative might be to use a map. The code would follow as

```
public class Values {
    public static Map<string,bool> variableMap;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {           
        // adding a 'variable'
        variableMap = new YourFavoriteMapImplementation();
        variableMap.put("enabled",true);

        // accessing the 'variables' value
        bool val = variableMap.get("enabled");
        System.out.println(val);         
    }
}
```